# Term for a value and derivatives at a given point

Tags: terminology

I'm doing some analysis which includes computing the sequence for some $f(t)$: $\left\{{f(t_0), \left.\frac{df}{dt}\right|_{t=t_0}}, \left.\frac{d^2f}{dt^2}\right|_{t=t_0}, \ldots ,\left.\frac{d^nf}{dt^n}\right|_{t=t_0} \right\}$, where n is some finite number.  Given its strong connection to Taylor series and its really useful properties, I'm thinking it probably has been given a name, but I can't seem to find one.

Does that series have a well recognized name (such that I could search for it to find additional properties)

Comment: Isn't this **actually** the Taylor series centred at $0$, or the Mclaurin series? Like, coefficients of the series times the factorial

Comment: @UmbQbify-Key20- The Taylor series includes not just these terms, but a factorial and a $(t-t_0)^k$ term.

Comment: The way all [these](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function) series are called sequences of some real numbers, I don't think there is a special name for that